# How to get image for a news read from an RSS?

Tags: rss, html-parsing, rss-reader

I'm creating an RSS reader software. the big problem is that there is no standard way to acquire images for news. In some cases, there is an 'Enclosure' property in the RSS items which contains the news image and it's the best one, in other cases I have to request for news item and search the HTML for a property names 'og' in meta tags and in the other cases I have to search wole HTML body for the image!
What should I do?

Comment: You just need to have fallbacks. Find the one in enclosure, if nothing, then OG, then try HTML, and so on.

Comment: The problem is HTML! how can I do it automatically?